# utopia font type in fourier package shrinks my document

Tags: fonts, fontsize, fourier

I would like to use the utopia font found in the `fourier` package, but when I add

```
\usepackage{fourier}
```

a 5 page document shrinks quite a lot, even though I'm using the same font size! The problem is that I'm required to use 10pt font for this document, and the `fourier` package with 10pt really looks smaller than that. Why does this happen? Aren't the fonts supposed to be the same size?

I checked the font size with the code found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125173/how-could-i-check-what-font-size-is-in-pt-for-section-subsection-and-subsub) and it's 10pt as expected in both cases.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry} % modify margins
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fourier}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[3-49]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are not comfortable going with 11pt in spite of the guidance, you could always use the `setspace` package to increase the interline skip distance slightly.

Comment: Going for 11 takes my document off the page limit with the current text so it's not an option.

Comment: `\usepackage{setspace}
\spacing{1.05}`

Comment: 11pt or 12pt give the *height* of the font. But just as handwriting, different fonts have different widths. Look at http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/seriffonts.html and compare, all have the same font size (height) but the test sentences have different lengths.

Comment: As I understood it, ``pt`` measure _used_ to indicate the full height of the metal body the characters were cast on. Today ``pt`` is a derivative of the ``em`` size, which I believe is set arbitrarily when the font is designed. Hence different fonts with the same point measure have different sizes. (I might be totally wrong about this)

Comment: Have a look at http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bleiletter.svg wher `$d$`  equals the font size.

Comment: If I remember correctly fourier scales the font a bit down to get better look together with the default linespacing. So it should be quite ok to use 11pt.

Comment: You can use the `widespace` option, which helps a bit. @UlrikeFischer I can't see where it does this. Are you thinking of `fouriernc`?

Comment: @cfr: It scales it by a factor of 0.92 in the virtual fonts. See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142725/using-10pt-fonts-with-the-fourier-package-actually-gives-me-9-17pt

Comment: Can someone point out a nice font that I can use that doesn't look smaller than 10pt but which also shrinks so that I can gain some space?

Comment: Thanks. Indeed: `(FONTAT R 0.92)`. It would be more flexible to do this in the `.fd` files, I think, with a customisable scaling factor?